# heroku nodejs app How can I get an absolute path to my app root directory?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a nodejs app.

How can I get an absolute path to my app root directory?
var rootDir = ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

var absolute_path = __dirname;

So far, I've only seen the root directory be "/app".

Comment: __dirname is not specific to heroku, that's provided by node, and appears to always be the absolute path.

Comment: thaks, but I need to set the current dir to my app dir regardless the actual current dir. so I do this, lack of better way:
        process.chdir('..');
        process.chdir('..');
        process.chdir('..');
        process.chdir('..');
        process.chdir('..');
        process.chdir('..');
        process.chdir('app');

Comment: the value of __dirname in the file in the root of your app is the value of your root dir.  So if you do chdir(__dirname) from that file, you have changed your current directory to your root directory

Answer (score 2):

After 3 years it is a little bit late, but for future genereations. 
Problems with __dirname is only relativ to file it was called.

I use path module of nodejs to get root path of my app

```
path.dirname(require.main.filename)
```